# Way for discord bot to listen and transcribe text from a voice channel

Tags: discord, bots, discord.py

Is there a way to allow for a discord bot that I am programming using the discord.py libraries in python to listen to what is being said inside a voice channel and then transcribe it. If this is possible, what methods are there to go about doing it?

Answer (score 1):

If they ever do plan on adding such a feature, it would need a continual feed of audio connected to your bot, which would likely be pretty intensive on storage collection, depending on whether your are surveilling or pumping this information.
Either way, it would be similar to the task which OBS has already accomplished here, using Google Speech Recognition: https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/closed-captioning-via-google-speech-recognition.833/.
If you look into this piece of software, you'll find that there is some kind of video.js plugin which is potentially free for user-devs (but unknown the kind of price for company.) I hope I was of useful help, and that you do find some manner of integrating this into one of your bots.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly this is still an experimental feature in discord.py and has yet to be implemented proper: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/1094

You can look for other libraries that support voice listening and then check out speech recognition for that language. Using Google helps a lot e.g. I found this [Discord Speech to Text Bot](https://gist.github.com/tyliec/ddcb3dd66328f8aa8e7384e0789ea01e).